# fitting more than one regression line to a scatterplot in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, regression

I'm trying to fit regression lines to this relation angc~ext. Variable pch divides the data into two sets to each of which I want to fit a regression line

with its confidence intervals. Here's my data frame (C):

```
"ext" "angc" "pch"
25 3.76288002820208 0
29 4.44255895177431 0
21 2.45214044383301 0
35 4.01334352881766 0
35 9.86225452423762 0
28 19.9304126868056 1
32 25.6984064030981 1
20 5.10582966112880 0
36 5.75603291081328 0
11 4.62311785943305 0
33 4.94401591414043 0
27 8.10039123328465 0
29 16.3882499757369 1
30 29.3492784626796 1
29 3.85960848290140 0
32 5.35857680326963 0
26 4.86451443776053 0
16 8.22008387344697 0
30 10.2212259432413 0
32 17.2519440101067 1
29 27.5011256290209 1
```

My code:

```
c0 <-  C[C$pch == 0, ]
c1 <- C[C$pch == 1, ]
prd0 <- as.data.frame( predict( lm(c0$angc ~ c0$ext), interval = c("confidence") ) )
prd1 <- as.data.frame( predict( lm(c1$angc ~ c1$ext), interval = c("confidence") ) )
dev.new()
plot( C$angc ~ C$ext, type = 'n' )
points( c0$angc ~ c0$ext, pch = 17 ) # triangles
abline(lm(c0$angc ~ c0$ext)) # regression line
lines(prd0$lwr) # lower CI
lines(prd0$upr) # upper CI
points( c1$angc ~ c1$ext, pch = 1 ) # circles
abline(lm(c1$angc ~ c1$ext))
lines(prd1$lwr, type = 'l', lty = 3 )
lines(prd1$upr, type = 'l', lty = 3 )
```

I have two problems:

1. How can I get the desired regression line for the circles? It should be an almost vertical line (check c1)
2. I don't get correct confidence intervals

Thank you for your help,

Santi

Comment: Despite my variables are numeric, I get this error: "Error in aes(x = ext, y = angc, shape = pch) + geom_point() : non-numeric argument to binary operator"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `ggplot2` you can do this rather efficiently:

```
ggplot(C, aes(x = ext, y = angc, shape = pch)) + geom_point() + 
     geom_smooth(method = "lm")
```

This will create a scatterplot (`geom_point()`) of `angc` vs `ext`, where the shape of the points is based on `pch`. In addition, a regression line is drawn in the plot for each unique element in `pch`. The name `geom_smooth()` comes from the fact that it draws a smoothed version of the data, in this case a linear regression.

Comment: Now I get another error: "A continuous variable can not be mapped to shape"

Comment: Your `pch` column is a numeric, convert it to a factor and try again.